# Socket not reading all the bytes from server

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a socket application that connects to a server and then recieves a buffer (size is known), but on slow networks the application does not recieve the full buffer here is my code

```
var bytes = new byte[65000];
Socket.Receive(bytes);
```

Comment: you need to loop incase it gets chunked.

Comment: Do you check how much bytes are left to be readed?

Comment: `Socket.Receive` returns an int which is the number of bytes received.

Comment: and do not get it. Use **alreadyRead=0; if (socket.Available>0)** and **int countRead = socket.GetStream().Read(b, 0, b.Length);** and **b.CopyTo(bytes, alreadyRead); alreadyRead+=countRead ;** until you get all the data

Comment: I didn't loop it in my code

Comment: @WhaChi We know. You should.

Comment: You do not get all the data at once. Read how work the sockets!!!

Comment: TCP's abstraction is a stream of bytes, of unknown length. If you want *messaging*, it's up to you to either implement that yourself or to pick a higher-level library that gives you a messaging abstraction.

Comment: I understand. where my problem lies. Donald Jansen Pointed out the problem that I had. This is working quite nicely. Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite easy, you can make the necesarry changes

```
    private byte[] ReadBytes(int size)
    {
        //The size of the amount of bytes you want to recieve, eg 1024
        var bytes = new byte[size];
        var total = 0;
        do
        {
            var read = _connecter.Receive(bytes, total, size - total, SocketFlags.None);
            Debug.WriteLine("Client recieved {0} bytes", total);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                //If it gets here and you received 0 bytes it means that the Socket has Disconnected gracefully (without throwing exception) so you will need to handle that here
            }
            total+=read;
            //If you have sent 1024 bytes and Receive only 512 then it wil continue to recieve in the correct index thus when total is equal to 1024 you will have recieved all the bytes
        } while (total != size);
        return bytes;
    }
```

To simulate this I have a test console app that generated the following out put to the Debug Console (with some threading and sleeping)

```
Server Sent 100 bytes
Server Sent 100 bytes
Server Sent 100 bytes
Server Sent 100 bytes
Server Sent 100 bytes
Server Sent 12 bytes
Client Reads 512 bytes
Client Recieved 100 bytes
Client Recieved 200 bytes
Client Recieved 300 bytes
Client Recieved 400 bytes
Client Recieved 500 bytes
Client Recieved 512 bytes
```

I had the same issue on an android application

Comment: Your code is not correct in the part where the client disconnects. You need to split this into two variables. One for the result of `Receive` (for example `receivedBytes`) and `total`. You need to check whether `receivedBytes == 0`, not `total == 0` as you may have received data before the connection drops. In that case, `total != 0` but `receivedBytes == 0`.

Comment: I would exchange variables "size" and "total" for clarity :-)

Comment: Something like this 
**var read = _connecter.Receive(bytes, total, size - total, SocketFlags.None);**
           **if (read == 0)
            {
                
            }**
**total+=read;**

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar you have a point there, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @WhaChi yes that is correct, I will update my answer

Answer (score 2):

The method `Socket.Receive` will return the number of the effective bytes that were read.

You cannot rely on the buffer size to get the full buffer read, because `Receive` returns if it does not receive data for a certain time. Think to `65000` as a **maximum** and not an **effective** buffer.

On a fast network you will get `buffer` to fill fast, but on a slow network packet delay will trigger `Receive` to flush itself to the buffer array.

In order to read fixed-sized buffers you may want to do:

```
public static byte[] ReadFixed (Socket this, int bufferSize) {
    byte[] ret = new byte[bufferSize];
    for (int read = 0; read < bufferSize; read += this.Receive(ret, read, ret.Size-read, SocketFlags.None));
    return ret;
}
```

The above was created as an extension method to the Socket class for more comfort of use. Code was hand-written.

Answer (score 2):

This way no need to set an initial read size, it fits to response.

```
public static byte[] ReceiveAll(this Socket socket)
{
    var buffer = new List<byte>();

    while (socket.Available > 0)
    {
        var currByte = new Byte[1];
        var byteCounter = socket.Receive(currByte, currByte.Length, SocketFlags.None);

        if (byteCounter.Equals(1))
        {
            buffer.Add(currByte[0]);
        }
    }

    return buffer.ToArray();
}
```